# Boolean Algebra: Explain why (M AND (NOT N)) OR (X AND M AND N) = (M AND NOT N) OR (X AND M)?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have no idea how this is true, by what theorem, and I literally have been thinking about this for 3 hours now.  I know it's really simple, but I just must not be in the right mindset to discover this now.

Here is (one of) the exact places where this is occurring:

```
= K'L'MN + MN'
= K'L'M + MN'
```

So you can see that N from the first term is getting dropped, due to some logical constraint I can't seem to fathom.  If you replace K'L' with X, and then use a 3-circle Venn Diagram, you'll see it's true there also.  But I was hoping someone could explain it in words, or at least Boolean algebra lemmas/rules.

Can someone explain why this is true?

Comment: You only have three variables, $X, M, N$, so it shouldn't be too hard to check via a [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

Comment: Oh I did, and it's true.  But I can't fathom why, in my head.  It's really bothering me, especially because it is so common/simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at $MN' + XMN$. We can write this as

$$\begin{align}
MN' + XMN &= M(N'+XN) \\
&= M((N'+X)(N'+N)) \\
&=M((N'+X)\cdot1)\\
&=M(N'+X)\\
&=MN'+XM
\end{align}$$

That's how you could do it with Boolean algebra. The only real trick was the $N'+XN=(N'+X)(N'+N)$ part, which uses the distributivity of AND and OR.

Comment: Good thinking to factor it that way.  Anyway, I think I'm done with this lemma for now -- I'm just going to commit it to memory.  It's too confusing to consistently do in your head.

Comment: How did you replace $N' + N$ with $1$?

Comment: (NOT N) OR N is always true. It's like saying "If it rains, I'll go to school. Or if it doesn't rain, I'll go to school." - you'll be going to school either way.